# Jar fails to load gui and crashes

Tags: java, jar, awt

I'm running into this nasty bug:

```
2013-06-18 15:06:01.908 java[3805:2617] Cocoa AWT: Apple AWT Java VM was loaded on first thread -- can't start AWT. (
    0   liblwawt.dylib                      0x000000016cf11ba2 JNI_OnLoad + 468
    1   libjava.dylib                       0x0000000109fbd6d1 Java_java_lang_ClassLoader_00024NativeLibrary_load + 207
    2   ???                                 0x000000010a093f90 0x0 + 4463345552
)
_NSJVMLoadLibrary: NSAddLibrary failed for /libjawt.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: lookup of function JAWT_GetAWT failed. Exit
```

My current intelliJ SDK is set to 1.6 for compatibility and i'm using Mountain Lion 10.8.4.
The interesting this is that it runs fine on intelliJ, but give me the above error when running:

```
java -jar jarfile.jar
```

The above code runs and opens the GUI application for a split second before closing and giving me the error. Thanks for helping out!

edit: the permission denied portion of the error has been removed as it was not a contributor to the specific error:

```
java -jar /Users/santoki/Documents/workspace/copakb\ client_b/copakb-client/out/artifacts/copakb_client_jar/copakb-client.jar
```

Edit 2:
I switched the target to 1.6 by doing, and get the following error:

```
Mac-mini:~ bigbitecode$ export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.6*'`
Mac-mini:~ bigbitecode$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06-451-11M4406)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01-451, mixed mode)
Mac-mini:~ bigbitecode$ java -jar /Users/bigbitecode/Documents/workspace/sys\ sys_b/sys-client/out/artifacts/sys_client_jar/sys-client.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: SysClient/data/gui/SysClient : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see a permission denied error you should try using `sudo` to run your command...

```
sudo java -jar jarfile.jar
```

You should also check any files that your jar accesses and make sure that you have set the correct permissions for the required operation. You can use chmod for this

```
sudo chmod a+rx <you_filename_here>
```

Comment: It helped omit the permission denied part, but it still shows the same error after it.

Comment: It sounds like it is working in your IntelliJ environment because its using the 1.6 target but your default system version might be 1.7... Can you check that you are running your jar using 1.6 target when you are running from the command line?

Comment: Run `java -version` to see what version is default on your system.

Comment: The default is 1.7, but I did run with 1.6 and I get the following: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: COPaClient/data/gui/COPaClient : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

 - I switched it by doing: export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.6*'`

Comment: Ok there is a bit of confusion going on here. That message comes from running classes compiled in a target higher then the runtime version. So it looks like you are possibly running source in 1.6 through IntelliJ then compiling in 1.7 and then trying to run in 1.6 from the command line. Are you compiling your source using IntelliJ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31979/discussion-between-travega-and-bigbitecode)